# Using bootstrap-confirmation into Update Panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, telerik

i have a RadGrid with multiple columns , and 1 columns is the delete one... it looks like this

```html
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn runat="server" HeaderText="Delete" HeaderStyle-Width="7%" UniqueName="Delete">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-success" data-toggle="confirmation" data-original-title="Are you sure you want to delete?" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"></asp:Button>
  </ItemTemplate>
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

i put the data-toggle="confirmation" on the button , it does what i expect to do , but after a partial postback , it stops working , the problem is from update panel , if i make it to do a complete postback it works how i want , but with async postbacks it doesn't want to

so can somebody help me with this ?

Comment: Where is your initialize javascript code ?

Comment: i use the default boostrap-confirmation,js code from Metronic theme... i just added it to my project ... full code here: http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/2KJP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following demo shows how you can use RadConfirm for this by adding a few lines of JS: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/window/examples/confirmserverclicks/defaultcs.aspx

Here are the most relevant snippets:

```
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Button" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" OnClientClick="confirmAspButton(this); return false;">
                </asp:Button>
```

and the JS

```
function confirmAspButton(button) {
    function aspButtonCallbackFn(arg) {
        if (arg) {
            __doPostBack(button.name, "");
        }
    }
    radconfirm("Are you sure you want to postback?", aspButtonCallbackFn, 330, 180, null, "Confirm");
}
```

Comment: not the thing I wanted to achieve but this works fine and I could make a workaround... Thank you

Comment: Glad it worked out. I know it is not exactly what you asked but its easy and close enough so I suggested anyway. Perhaps you could post your implementation as well for others who have a similar scenario?

Comment: i used boostrap for all the buttons  outside of Radgrid... and for radgrid buttons i made a radwindow confirm, and it looks better than what i wanted to do